# Does php redefine constants on every request?

Tags: php, request

I saw some people use this syntax in their code in the index.php or in the configuration file

```
defined('SOME_CONSTANT') || define('SOME_CONSTANT','SOME_VALUE');
```

while I understand what it means (if defined leaved it as it is, otherwise define it), but why to look if it is defined or not if it will be undefined at the beginning of the script ?

AFAIK PHP re-executes the script on every single request, so what's the point from using "defined".

Comment: Because constants may be defined/created in other places. For example, there are some built in constants - https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.constants.php. This code is just checking if it has been defined, and it not it will define it.

Comment: I guess these could be used for a fallback default.  In code that runs before you could just override: `const SOME_CONSTANT = 'foo';`

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 0):

**define()** method use to set Constant Value in Application. Where **defined()** use to
check whether the given constant exists and is defined.

If you not checked the given constant existence then it'll be make an error for undefined constant in application.

*Note:
If you want to see if a variable exists, use isset() as defined() only applies to constants. If you want to see if a function exists, use function_exists().*

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php , https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Answer (score 0):

Consider constants defined in files that may or may not have been included or files that can be accessed directly or accessed via an `include/require`:

If you were to access `https://example.com/index.php?page=test` then the constant is defined and `test.php` is included:

```
// index.php
define('INDEX', true);
include($_GET['page'] . '.php');  // example only, don't do this!
```

Opposed to accessing `https://example.com/test.php` directly where the constant has not been defined:

```
// test.php
defined('INDEX') || define('INDEX', false);
```

It is just like other variables that may or may not be set, such as in the example above when accessing `https://example.com/index.php`:

```
isset($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] = 'default';
// or more likely
$page = $_GET['page'] ?: 'default';
```